# Remove extra line appearing in the top

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

Question: While i am adding page numbering one line appear in the header, how to get rid from it? Even see the starting of my document, in fact i want to reduce that top margin.

What i have :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[width=0.00cm, height=0.00cm, left=0.70in, right=0.70in, top=0.70in, bottom=0.70in]{geometry}
%pagestyle
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\begin{document}
Starting of document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}` to the preamble.

Comment: @esdd Its working thanks you. What about other issue please guide me.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy if you're speaking about reducing the top margin as the other issus, you can simply do it thanks to the option top=0.70in of the geometry package. Change the value, with the unit that you like.

Comment: Off topic: remove `width=0cm` and `height=0cm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule above the text can be removed by `\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}`. To reduce the top margin decrease the value of geometry option `top` and add option `nohead`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[
  left=0.70in, right=0.70in,
  top=0.2in,% <- changed, you can adjust the length to your needs
  nohead,% <-added
  bottom=0.70in
]{geometry}
%pagestyle
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}% <- added
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}
Starting of document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great help for me.